# undetected chromedriver close Automatically After Few Seconds

Tags: python, selenium, python-webbrowser, undetected-chromedriver

I am facing a problem with my code:
undetected chromedriver close Automatically After Few Seconds
i wish you can help me♥.
this image show the error:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui
import time
print("ready?")
print("loading.......................................")
df = pd.read_excel("Moaaz.xlsx","Moaaz")
email = "sisoasn81@gmail.com"
password = "1*1#36@$%anz"
name = df["Name"].values.tolist()
website = df["Website"].values.tolist()
phone = df["Phone"].values.tolist()
logo = df["Logo"].values.tolist()
firm_map = df["Firm map"].values.tolist()

if "PROGRAMFILES(X86)" not in os.environ:
    os.environ["PROGRAMFILES(X86)"] = ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
    driver.get('https://www.blogger.com/blog/posts/3793019451239403430')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    time.sleep(10)

    for s in range(len(name)):
        #click new post
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('U26fgb O0WRkf zZhnYe e3Duub C0oVfc zr7Fj zFM5pd M9Bg4d').click()
        #enter name dog
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf').send_keys(name[s])
        #convert to html view
        pyautogui.leftClick(627, 707)
        pyautogui.leftClick(455, 206)
        pyautogui.leftClick(149, 279)
        driver.stop_client()
```

i wish you can help me♥ i try to solve it but i can't.

Comment: يوسف محمد i think its time to update your password.

Comment: it is fake pro ♥

Comment: it's a standard exception... try/catch your calls.  You probably also want to use webdriverwaits with expected conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You got "unable to locate element" excption.
You might implement waiting for the element to appear and also check, if it is the correct Element-id (at `driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)`